# Is there a Replay icon for material-table and how do I target it?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I am using remote data fetching feature with material table. Whenever an error is thrown, the table displays an error as shown in the image below[material-table error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zATq.png)

I have been able to target and replace most of material table icons but I can't seem to figure out how to update the **replay** icon expected .Clicking the **replay** text reloads the table as expected.

I have tried passing a Replay icon to the table icons as I have done with most icons as shown below but this does not work.[custom material-table icons code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2IpX.png)

When I inspect the replay text/icon this is the html rendered [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIgRI.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.